# Decrypt string Encrypted using mysql aes_encryption function

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, openssl, aes

For a project requirement I need to store values in encrypted format in mysql.
Decryption and encryption should be possible in both side PHP and Mysql.
I tried using openssl encrypt decrypt. In mysql for version less than 5.7 we cannot set encryption mode. Default mode is aes-128-ecb. When I try to decrypt using same mode in openssl I get null.

Query : SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('ABCD', '69f0ff56314d4e2d02bc89f6f4b5292c') FROM tbl_name;

Result : 0x907fb5ce60223d205e7c0f0bc338d563

When i pass this result to PHP :

```
<?php
$plaintext = "0x907fb5ce60223d205e7c0f0bc338d563";
$cipher = "aes-128-ecb";
$key = "69f0ff56314d4e2d02bc89f6f4b5292c";
if(in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {
  $ciphertext = openssl_decrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key);
  echo $ciphertext;
}
```

It doesn't work. Any idea what I am missing or any other way to implement this?
Mysql version : 5.0
PHP : 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues within your PHP-code but the most important is to "derive" the decryption key from the given key via a function that is nowhere named in the MySQL documentation.

I got the information and the function from this site and **all credits go to them**: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/.

The other issues were a) that the ciphertext is a hex encoded string of the binary representation and b) the "true" parameter at the end of the openssl_decrypt function [take data as binary and not Base64 encoded].

**Security warning: this code is using the UNSECURE AES mode 'EBC', a static key and has no exception handling**. The code is for educational purpose only.

This is the simple and expected output - you can run the code via my online compiler (https://repl.it/@javacrypto/PhpAesDecryptFromMysql):

```
ABCD
```

Full running source code:

```
<?php

function mysql_aes_key($key)
// source: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/
{
    $new_key = str_repeat(chr(0), 16);
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($key); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $new_key[$i % 16] = $new_key[$i % 16] ^ $key[$i];
    }
    return $new_key;
}

$ciphertextFromMysql = "907fb5ce60223d205e7c0f0bc338d563";
$key = "69f0ff56314d4e2d02bc89f6f4b5292c";

$ciphertext = hex2bin($ciphertextFromMysql);
$cipher = "aes-128-ecb";

if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {
    //$ciphertext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, true);
    $decrypttext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, mysql_aes_key($key), true);
    echo $decrypttext;
}
?>
```